# How do I create a floating tikz figure when exporting to PDF in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-babel, pdf

With org-mode 8.2.10 on Emacs 24.5.1, the following will produce a ditaa figure in the exported PDF (LaTeX):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa :file foo.png :cmdline -E -s 4 -S
+---------+
| testing |
+---------+
#+END_SRC
#+CAPTION: ditaa caption
#+LABEL: fig:ditaa
#+attr_latex: :width 1in
#+RESULTS:
[[file:foo.png]]
```

If I try to do the same thing but using tikz to generate a figure, it does not work.  The following example (copied from [the org-mode documentation](http://orgmode.org/tmp/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html#sec-4_2_2)) simply produces a PDF containing the string "[[file:fsa.pdf]]".

```
#+begin_src latex :file fsa.pdf :packages '(("" "tikz")) :border 1em
  % Define block styles
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
  \tikzstyle{astate} = [circle, draw, text centered, font=\footnotesize, fill=blue!25]
  \tikzstyle{rstate} = [circle, draw, text centered, font=\footnotesize, fill=red!25]

  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=2.8cm, semithick]
    \node [astate] (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \node [astate] (2) at (1,0) {2};
    \node [rstate] (3) at (2,0) {3};
    \path (1) edge [bend left] node {b} (2)
          (2) edge node {b} (3)
          (2) edge [bend left] node {a} (1)
          (3) edge [loop above] node {(a, b)} (3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
#+CAPTION: tikz caption
#+LABEL: fig:tikz
#+RESULTS:
[[file:fsa.pdf]]
```

How do I generate a floating tikz figure without manually using `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the result file is put between `#+BEGIN/END_LaTeX` marks (eg type `C-c C-c` inside the src block.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They key is to add a `:results raw` header argument ([documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html)) to the `#+BEGIN_SRC` line to prevent org-mode from wrapping the results in `#+BEGIN_LaTeX`/`#+END_LaTeX`:

```
#+begin_src latex :file fsa.pdf :packages '(("" "tikz")) :border 1em :results raw
  % Define block styles
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
  \tikzstyle{astate} = [circle, draw, text centered, font=\footnotesize, fill=blue!25]
  \tikzstyle{rstate} = [circle, draw, text centered, font=\footnotesize, fill=red!25]

  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=2.8cm, semithick]
    \node [astate] (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \node [astate] (2) at (1,0) {2};
    \node [rstate] (3) at (2,0) {3};
    \path (1) edge [bend left] node {b} (2)
          (2) edge node {b} (3)
          (2) edge [bend left] node {a} (1)
          (3) edge [loop above] node {(a, b)} (3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
#+CAPTION: tikz caption
#+LABEL: fig:tikz
#+RESULTS:
[[file:fsa.pdf]]
```

Comment: Is this still working for folks? For me, the pdf file produced is in the local directory and has a random hash file name, org seems to look for it in the temporary files (but it's not there), and it can't be found. The `:file fsa.pdf` seems to have no effect, but I think that's because the org system gets confused about where the temp file went (it's in the local directory instead of the temp directory).